# In ConnectionFactory.php line 274: Unsupported driver [mongodb]

Tags: laravel, mysql-connector, sanctum

I installed sanctum in my comany project (laravel9). when I used the command "php artisan migrate" it errored "In ConnectionFactory.php line 274: Unsupported driver [mongodb]".

While i use mysql and in my .env file the database is mysql. this is the error part of mentioned file(ConnectionFactory.php line 274).

```
protected function createConnection($driver, $connection, $database, $prefix = '', array $config = [])
    {
        if ($resolver = Connection::getResolver($driver)) {
            return $resolver($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
        }

        return match ($driver) {
            'mysql' => new MySqlConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config),
            'pgsql' => new PostgresConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config),
            'sqlite' => new SQLiteConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config),
            'sqlsrv' => new SqlServerConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config),
            default => throw new InvalidArgumentException("Unsupported driver [{$driver}]."),
        };
    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are clearly passing mongodb as driver to this function instead of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

change your `DB_CONNECTION` from MongoDB to MySQL or one of the supported database drivers.

supported drivers:

- `mysql`
- `pgsql`
- `sqlite`
- `sqlsrv`

Comment: my DB_CONNECTION Wwas mysql already.